# Manim, ReplacementTransform without Transform

Tags: python, manim

I'm new to manim.

as with following example,

```py
class scene_example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        txt1 = Text("Text1")
        txt2 = Text("Change to this text without animation")

        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        self.play(ReplacementTransform(txt1, txt2))
```

Is there any convenient function for "Replace" the txt1 to txt2? (i.e., without the "transforming" animation?)

```py
class scene_example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        txt1 = Text("Text1")
        txt2 = Text("Change to this text without animation")
        
        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        self.play(FadeOut(txt1), FadeIn(txt2) )
```

This code will do what I want, but I feel that there might function like ReplacemnetTransform to fulfill the simple "Replacement" animation. I tried to make a function for FadeIn and then FadeOut but, that doesn't work.

```py
class q(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def Replace(self, mObj1, mObj2):
            self.play(FadeIn(mObj1),FadeOut(mObj2))

        txt1 = "HI"
        txt2 = "HI2"

        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        Replace(txt1, txt2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code that you tried to write:

```
class q(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def Replace(self, mObj1, mObj2):
            self.play(FadeIn(mObj1),FadeOut(mObj2))

        txt1 = Text("HI")
        txt2 = Text("HI2")

        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        Replace(txt1, txt2)
```

the parameter `self` doesn't get passed to the `Replace` function automatically. One solution is to replace
`Replace(txt1, txt2)`
with
`Replace(self, txt1, txt2)`.

Another option is to not make `Replace` take the self parameter at all. The code

```
class q(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        def Replace(mObj1, mObj2):
            self.play(FadeIn(mObj1),FadeOut(mObj2))

        txt1 = Text("HI")
        txt2 = Text("HI2")

        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        Replace(txt1, txt2)
```

should also work. In this case because of how scoping works in python, the `self` inside `Replace` refers to the `self` parameter passed to the `construct` method. In the previous example where `Replace` had its own `self` parameter, the `self` parameter masks the one passed to `construct`, and the `self` within `Replace` refers to `Replace`'s `self`. (Which by default doesn't have any value unless one is given when calling `Replace`. In fact, when you tried to run your code, you probably got an error along the lines of
`TypeError: Replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mObj2'`)

Yet another possibility is to define `Replace` inside the `q` class, but outside the `construct` method:

```
class q(Scene):
    def Replace(self, mObj1, mObj2):
        self.play(FadeIn(mObj1),FadeOut(mObj2))

    def construct(self):
        txt1 = Text("HI")
        txt2 = Text("HI2")

        self.play(FadeIn(txt1))
        self.Replace(txt1, txt2)
```

Additionally, if you just want to replace the initial text with some new text with no animations at all (not even the fading in and out), then you can use

```
self.remove(txt1)
self.add(txt2)
```

A much more complicated option is to create a custom `Animation` class that is instantiated with two MObjects, and fades the first one out while fading the second one in.

```
class FadingReplace(Animation):
  def __init__(self, obj1, obj2, ...):
    pass
#implementation left as an exercise for the reader
```

Then you could use

```
self.play(FadingReplace(txt1, txt2))
```

Comment: Dylan, Thank you for the precise answer! Creating a Custom Animation class sounds exciting for me. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Not much contribution to answer, however if user want to replace first text to another one

```
class q(Scene):
    def replace(self, obj1, obj2):
        self.play(
            ApplyMethod(obj1.move_to, obj2),
            FadeOut(obj2),
            run_time=3)

    def construct(self):
        txt1 = Text("HI").shift(LEFT*3)

        txt2 = Text("HI2").shift(RIGHT*3)
        self.add(txt1, txt2)
        self.replace(txt1, txt2)
        self.wait(1)
```